# I try to run Steam and I get this in the terminal

Tags: steam

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
/home/mason_parks/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2020-08-27 19:05:10] Startup - updater built Jul 31 2020 09:12:07
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1596217132)
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1596217132)
[2020-08-27 19:05:10] Checking for update on startup
[2020-08-27 19:05:10] Checking for available updates...
[2020-08-27 19:05:10] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1596217132)
[2020-08-27 19:05:11] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1596217132, installed version 1596217132
[2020-08-27 19:05:11] Nothing to do
[2020-08-27 19:05:11] Verifying installation...
[2020-08-27 19:05:11] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-08-27 19:05:11] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.13-5893924
Gtk-Message: 19:05:11.901: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 19:05:11.902: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:27242): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:05:11.909: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/ZorinGrey-Dark/gtk-2.0/main.rc:1111: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
/usr/share/themes/ZorinGrey-Dark/gtk-2.0/apps.rc:91: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1596217132)
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
[0827/190514.340926:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: browser
[0827/190514.366029:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0827/190514.366110:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1596186727
[0827/190514.366117:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0827/190514.366122:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0827/190514.402318:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0827/190514.402377:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1596186727
[0827/190514.402385:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0827/190514.402391:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0827/190514.402952:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: gpu-process
[0827/190514.429751:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(372)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0827/190514.451425:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0827/190514.451489:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1596186727
[0827/190514.451494:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0827/190514.451498:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(286)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0827/190514.452054:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(247)] Crash reporting enabled for process: utility
assert_20200827190510_1.dmp[27313]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20200827190510_1.dmp
assert_20200827190510_1.dmp[27313]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20200827190510_1.dmp[27313]: response: CrashID=bp-af1febef-cc46-42c6-a1b7-443b82200827
assert_20200827190510_1.dmp[27313]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20200827190510_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-af1febef-cc46-42c6-a1b7-443b82200827''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt install libatk-adaptor libgail-common`.